# How to test if there is left over after using a regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex

Example Input:

```
john@test.com johnny@myserver.com      joan@server.com
```

With an regular expression like `[a-z]+@[a-z]+.com` we can find alle mail addresses in the given input string. **Note:** The regular expression is simplified to keep the example easy.

**Question:** Is there a way to check if the left over of the input string (which did not match the pattern) only consists of whitespace, so that we can test, whether each mail address was regocnized by the pattern or not?

Comment: A possible solution would be to remove the match from the input (ever time a match is found) until there are no matches anymore and then have a look at what left in the input string or negate the whole regex and retrieve the result.

Comment: @pasty thank you. I did something different: Using "^\s*([a-z]+@[a-z]+.com\s*)*$" we can check if the given input string matches only whitespace or some of the mail addresses (separated by whitespace). Then I just use  match.Success : True, no left over exists; false, left over does exist. Do I miss something?

Comment: I am not sure, sorry. Your solution returns true also for a string containing only whitespaces. You should definitively try using the suggestion of @quetzalcoatl - a combination of captures and removing matches from the input should work well. After all matches are removed, then there be only leftovers in the string - all non matches. Maybe i can't understand your solution entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Use grouping and captures.

Use a regex like `\s*([a-z]+@[a-z]+.com)\s*` (note the extra parenthesis! important!), an then instead of looking at what regex has matched as a whole, get the matchresult object and inspect its groups and captures. From that, you will get not one email, but a list of all emails that were caught (and that were separated by whitespaces)

EDIT:

First, check [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for overview about "groups" and "captures".

Then, note that [Regex.Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns an object of [class `Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which tells you whether there was a `Success` or not. But, aside from the `Success` property on that `Match` object, there are some other properties like `Captures` or `Groups`.

Those two properties of `Match` are collections that keep all strings that were, well, 'captured' by any 'group' (parenthesis) that occurred in the regex.

Depending on how you have structured your regex, the contents of Captures and Groups will differ, but just see them for yourself and it should be clear what/how they work.

For example:

```
regex: (aaa([b0-9]+)ccc([d0-9]+)eee\s*)*
input: "aaab123cccd456eee aaab789cccd123deee"
```

will result in 3 groups (because there are 3 sets of parenthesis) and 6 captures (because the regex matched two big strings and small parens matched twice in each of the big string)

```
groups:
   [0] captures: "aaab123cccd456eee ", "aaab789cccd123deee"
   [1] captures: "b123", "b789"
   [2] captures: "d456", "d123"
```

Note that there's a space in the "big" capture from the "big" parenthesis, since I've included the `\s*` token at the end of it to account for the separator.

Comment: Thank you. I do not fully understand your suggestion. Can you explain the inspection of groups and captures more detailed, please? I am not quite familiar with this.

Comment: Check the edit. Please write some sample, and look what a `Match` and its `Groups` contains. It will tell you probably much more.